# finding limit of $\lim_{x\to -2}\frac{\sqrt{6+x}-2}{\sqrt{3+x}-1}$

Tags: limits

Find $\lim_{x\to -2}\frac{\sqrt{6+x}-2}{\sqrt{3+x}-1}$

L'Hopital's Rule is not allowed for this question. I tried conjugation but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Try conjugation for both the numerator AND the denominator. Work out the algebra, and let us know what your simplified answer is! We'll help you out from there.

Comment: oh i didn't consider doing both conjugation!! thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

**HINT** 
$$\begin{align} \lim\limits_{x\to-2}\dfrac{\sqrt{6+x}-2}{\sqrt{3+x}-1} &= \lim\limits_{x\to-2}\dfrac{\sqrt{6+x}-2}{\sqrt{3+x}-1}  \times\dfrac{\sqrt{6+x}+2}{\sqrt{3+x}+1} \times \dfrac{\sqrt{3+x}+1}{\sqrt{6+x}+2} \\~\\ &= ?\end{align} $$